# MLKit using jetpack compose flips the Graphic overlay drawing horizontally

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-mlkit

Developing the pose detector app on android Kotlin using Jetpack compose. The graphic overlay is getting flipped when using the from camera. As Im new to compose development, any help here will be appreciated. Have tried using MLAnalyzer as well, but still the flipping continues. However, when back camera is used it works as intended.

There is a question already asked and answered. But unable to get much info from that answer.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75515945/ml-kit-pose-graphic-overlay-compose-implementation-not-working-as-intended](https://stackoverflow.com)

I tried using the Matrix transformation, however, not sure how to implement on Jetpack Compose for graphic overlay.